# VB Login system resource issue

Tags: vb.net, authentication

I'm working on a login system for a program that I am creating using VB. There are two problems with the system at the moment: the first is that even if the user has created an account, the username and password files appear to be wiped when the program starts; and secondly when I try to log in, it throws up this error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\Resources\username.txt' because it is being used by another process."

The code for the system is as follows:

```
    Imports System.IO

Public Class Login

Private Sub Login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private usernameWriter As New StreamWriter("J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\Resources\username.txt") 'Creates the stream for writing the username to file

Private passwordWriter As New StreamWriter("J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\Resources\password.txt") 'Creates the stream for writing the password to file

Dim currentLogin As String 'Allows the program to recognise which user is logged in currently

Private Sub btn_CreateAccount_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_CreateAccount.Click
    usernameWriter.WriteLine(txtbox_UsernameCreate.Text) 'Writes the username to the username file.
    passwordWriter.WriteLine(txtbox_PasswordCreate.Text) 'Writes the password to the password file.
    usernameWriter.Close() 'Closes the username file after writing to it so that changes are saved to the file.
    passwordWriter.Close() 'Closes the password file for the same reason as the username file above.
    currentLogin = txtbox_UsernameCreate.Text
    Dim statsFile As New StreamWriter("J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\Resources\" + currentLogin + ".txt")
    Tokyo.Show() 'Tokyo is the name for the main menu
    Me.Hide() 'As Login is the startup form for this solution, it is hidden instead of closed so that the program will not terminate when the login screen dissapears.
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Login.Click
    Dim usernameReader As New StreamReader("J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\Resources\username.txt") 'Sets the location for the username to be found in

    Dim passwordReader As New StreamReader("J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\Resources\password.txt") 'Sets the location for the password to be found in

    Dim n As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    While n < 101 'Checks the first 100 lines for the username
        If txtbox_UsernameCreate.Text = usernameReader.ReadLine Then 'If the username is found close the usernameReader and move on to the password
            usernameReader.Close()
            While i < 101 'checks the first 100 password entries
                If txtboxPassword.Text = passwordReader.ReadLine Then 'If the password is found then close the passwordReader, set the login ID and then open the main menu
                    passwordReader.Close()
                    currentLogin = txtbox_UserName.Text
                    Me.Hide()
                    Tokyo.Show()
                Else
                    i += 1 'otherwise it increments the count so that the next line can be read
                End If
                MsgBox("No valid password") 'If the first 100 lines have been checked and there is no password then this returns the msgbox
            End While
        Else
            n += 1 'otherwise it increments the count so that the next line can be read
        End If
        MsgBox("No valid username") 'If the first 100 lines have been checked and there is no username then this returns the msgbox
    End While
End Sub
End Class
```

Any help with the above problem would be a considerable help.

Comment: why not read the files all at once into a List(of String) (or List(Of UserPW)) so that you can close the files.  by "wiped" do you mean the files are empty?  At the very least, you also should close the files you open before you leave the form.  Me.Hide is leaving them open.

Comment: If I use me.close(), then the program will terminate as it is the form that loads on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay:

The reason your files are being wiped out is that you are creating your `StreamWriter` objects at the time you declare them.  `StreamWriter` objects open a file and prepare to write to it as soon as they are created, and module-level variables that have initializers are created as soon as the parent class is instantiated, so, as you have seen, the first thing that happens is that your files are overwritten.

Also, since opening a file for writing requires locking it, any attempt to access your file for reading will fail.  That's why you're getting that error.

You really shouldn't be creating your `StreamWriter` objects so far in advance of using them.  You should create them at the last possible moment.  You can *declare* them ahead of using them, but don't *instantiate* them (`new` them) until you need them, and close or dispose of them as soon as you're done with them.

(The same principle - create at last moment, dispose after use - applies to readers, as well.)

ETA:  Here's what the declaration should look like:

```
 Private usernameWriter As StreamWriter  'The stream for writing the username to file
 Private passwordWriter As StreamWriter  'The stream for writing the password to file
```

Then, when it's time to use them, create them, use them, and close them, like this:

```
 usernameWriter = new StreamWriter("J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\Resources\username.txt")
 usernameWriter.WriteLine(txtbox_UsernameCreate.Text) 'Writes the username to the username file.
 usernameWriter.Close()

 passwordWriter = new StreamWriter("J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\Resources\password.txt")
 passwordWriter.WriteLine(txtbox_PasswordCreate.Text) 'Writes the password to the password file.
 passwordWriter.Close()
```

Comment: I have removed the 'New' part of the declaration, however the an error appears: "array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers"

Comment: `Private usernameWriter As StreamWriter`